# Encontrar um menor valor de uma coleção, de acordo com uma condição

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Eu tenho duas coleções: A e B como `List<int>`, ambas com o mesmo tamanho **N**.
Na coleção A, estão os projetos.
Na B, as **ofertas** pelo projeto.

Ilustrando:
projetos[5, 1, 4, 5]
ofertas[8, 7, 6, 9]
Logo,

Para o projeto **5**, tenho as ofertas: [8,9]
Para o **1**: [7]
Para o **4**: [6]

Eu gostaria de retornar um menor valor possível entre as ofertas para cada projeto, seguindo o exemplo ilustrado.
Que no caso irá ficar **8 + 7 + 6 = 21**

Por favor, alguém poderia me ajudar ou me indicar uma outra solução(links, referências, etc)?

Aqui está o enunciado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu fiz, até o momento:

```
internal static long minCost(int numProjects, List<int> projectId, List<int> bid)
    {
        var projectsBids = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        int minValue = 0;

        List<int> projects = projectId.Distinct().ToList();


        if (projects.Count != numProjects)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < projects.Count; i++)
        {
            //Aqui eu preciso adicionar valores que estão para o projeto(projects[i]), mas não sei como
            projectsBids.Add(projects[i], /*aqui*/);

        }

        return minValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde Álvaro.

Não ficou claro como você está vinculando as duas coleções.
Talvez, nesse cenário, a melhor opção seja usar um *Dictionary<int, List>*.
Dessa forma, você teria como chave o ID do projeto e como valor o List com as ofertas.
Dessa forma você pode usar a instrução Min() pra pegar a menor oferta daquele projeto específico.
Para ficar menos verboso, vc pode combinar isso com o Select e mandando somar no final, pra chegar no valor que você comentou.
Por exemplo:

```
var projetosEOfertas = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

projetosEOfertas.Add(5, new List<int> { 8, 9 });
projetosEOfertas.Add(1, new List<int> { 7 });
projetosEOfertas.Add(4, new List<int> { 6 });

var total = projetosEOfertas.Select(_ => _.Value.Min()).Sum();
```

Se puder mandar mais detalhes de como é feito atualmente esse vínculo entre projetos e ofertas, podemos dar outras opções.

Comment: Opa Eduardo. Muito obrigado pela resposta!
Eu pensei também em adicionar em uma Dictonary<int, List<int>>, mas fiquei com dúvida de como adicionar os items na listas para cada chave.
O vínculo entre projeto e ofertas é apenas a posição I de cada coleção, sempre as duas coleções tem o mesmo tamanho.
Eu pensei na relação 1 projeto para 1-N ofertas.

Comment: Isso é um exercício do hacker hank, que precisei fazer para uma entrevista, mas não consegui terminar.
Eu gostaria de resolver, para uma próxima tentativa.

Comment: eu adicionei mais detalhes. Obrigado novamente!

Comment: Consegui resolver :D! Vlw Eduardo, usei a sua consulta!

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi! Se alguém precisar, segue o código:

```
internal static long minCost(int numProjects, List<int> projectId, List<int> bid)
    {
        var projectsBids = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        int minValue = 0;

        List<int> projects = projectId.Distinct().ToList();


        if (projects.Count != numProjects)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < projects.Count; i++)
        {
            projectsBids.Add(projects[i], new List<int> { });
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < projects.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < projectId.Count; j++)
            {
                if (projectId[j] == projects[i])
                {
                    projectsBids[projects[i]].Add(bid[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        minValue = projectsBids.Select(_ => _.Value.Min()).Sum();

        return minValue;
    }
```

Comment: Ótimo. Sucesso então!